# Friendly url Is not working smarty

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, smarty, prestashop

I am new to it. So maybe I am doing some silly mistakes. But i will try to explain my question in details.

So I've set my url `mycarshop/en/module/car?name=carBrand` to friendly url `mycarshop/car/carBrand` i used

**.htaccess mod_rewrite**

```
RewriteRule ^car/([^_]*)\.html$ /en/module/car?name=$1 [L]
```

But now i can't set my link to get carBrand and to use carBrand controller

OldUrl: `mycarshop/en/module/car?name=MD`

**language: lang-html**

```
<a> href="{$link->getModuleLink('module','carBrand',['name'=>$car.brand])}" title="{$car.brand|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}"</a>
```

and it works fine, but after setting friendly url i don't know how to linked it correctly

NewUrl: `www.mycarshop/car/MD`

**language: lang-html**

```
<a> href="{car/$car.brand}" title="{$car.brand|escape:'htmlall':'utf-8'}"</a>
```

It must be something like that and still using carBrand `carBrand.php` controller.

Comment: @anubhava [Syntax highlighting for code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) and [Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Which version of prestashop you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the variable with the folder name. It will probably work with `href="car/{$car.brand}"`